# CartoAPIError: Map instantiation API request failed?

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, deck.gl, cartodb, vector-tiles

I'm trying to debug a weird error with Carto and Deck GL. The exact text of the error is as follows:

> Uncaught (in promise) CartoAPIError: Map instantiation API request failed
> Server returned: Not found (404): Connection not found

The relevant code chunk is as follows:

```
    const polyLayer = (deckgl, longitude, latitude) => {
      if (longitude && latitude) { 
        console.log(longitude, latitude) 
        return new deck.carto.CartoLayer({
            id: 'block',
            connection: 'bigquery',
            type: deck.carto.MAP_TYPES.QUERY,
            data: `SELECT dist_miles, geometry AS geom 
                      FROM \`bleeding-out.census_blocks.blocks_optimized\`
                      WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(ST_GEOGPOINT(${longitude}, ${latitude}), geometry)`,
            getFillColor: deck.carto.colorContinuous({
              attr: "dist_miles",
              domain: [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30],
              colors: [[255, 247, 236, 150], 
                        [254, 232, 200, 150], 
                        [253, 212, 158, 150], 
                        [253, 187, 132, 150], 
                        [252, 141, 89, 150], 
                        [239, 101, 72, 150], 
                        [215, 48, 31, 150], 
                        [179, 0, 0, 150], 
                        [127, 0, 0, 150], 
                        [102, 31, 31, 150], 
                        [77, 0, 0, 150]]
            }),
            getLineColor: false,
            lineWidthMaxPixels: 0,
            useDevicePixels:false,
            pickable: true,
            filled: true
          })
        }
          return null;
        }
```

I've tried Googling this error and there are no references to it. I've also read through the Carto documentation and been through the examples multiple times and have come up with anything that works.

I've also tried using `deck.carto.MAP_TYPES.TILESET` with a tileset version of the same data and swapping `bqconn` for `bigquery` (I've seen both online).

I can see that the lat/long is getting inherited from the console so that's not the problem.

[image: console error]

Puzzlingly, inside BigQuery this exact same query totally works:

[image: BigQuery Google SQL query result]

I'm copy-pasting the qualified name straight from Carto data warehouse so its not a problem there either.

Truly stumped on this one, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does carto connect to bigquery? Are you sure that connection is valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the CartoLayer `connection` prop. The connection name is not `bigquery` no `bqconn`. You need to use the same name you have given to the connection in the CARTO Workspace.

Comment: I actually figured this out myself awhile ago, but you are absolutely right. The documentation is not clear about this IMHO.